# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This error is occurring when i import button from material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

This error is occurring while I was importing the button class from material-ui.

in my App.js file when I add the Button tag and import '@material-ui/core' from material-ui it gives me an error that Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. so what I do now I don't know. I am new to react-js. please help me to reach out of this problem...

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import './App.css';

function App() {

        const [todos,setTodos] = useState(['take dogs for a walk','take the rubbish out','help them who cant help back']);
        const [input, setInput] = useState('');
        console.log('hassam:',input);
        const addTodo= (event)=>  {
          //fire off when you click Add Todo button...
          event.preventDefault(); //will stop the refreshing...
          console.log('it got tapped'); 
          // setTodos([...todos,'here is the new to do'])
          setTodos([...todos,input])
          setInput('');  //its clearing the input field...
        }
        
        
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
      <input value={input} onChange={event=>setInput(event.target.value)}/>
      
      <Button type='submit' onClick={addTodo} variant="contained" color="primary">
          Add Todo
          </Button>
      
      </form>
     
      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => (<li>{todo}</li>))}

      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What happens if you change the button type to "button" instead of "submit" so you don't submit the form? Copied your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com-qphpv) and see no issues. Can you verify the versions of React and Material-UI? Or create a *running* codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue?

Comment: What version of Material-ui are you using

Comment: thanks bro for replaying me. I have found the error was i have installed the material-ui (npm install @material-ui/core) node module components in another folder i was working on my project in another folder so that is why this error was occurring...